# ios retractable menu?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm trying to figure out how to make a retractable menu (left panel) as gmail app or facebook app...

I don't know how to move just part of the front window to show the menu (in another view) when you tap on the corresponding button.

Can you give me some clue on how to do it?

Comment: The library is called [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). Give it a try.

Comment: If you put this as answer I can mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom container controller and use affine trasforms to the view controller's view.